# Assembly do we need the endings?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att

In assembly (att) the following is legal:

```
mov %rax, %rbx
```

which is equal to:

```
movq %rax, %rbx
```

Where q means the **first parameter** is 64 bits, my question is:

Is this q (or other endings) used only for simplicity of human reading or there could be some cases where no writing q would give wrong answer or different result than the expected one or even crash the code (illegal command), please give me an example if possible.

Comment: `movq $1, (%rbx)` needs the Q to determine the size of the memory operand.

Comment: I think there have been other duplicates of this, as well as the one I linked, but maybe only for NASM.  (It's the same for all assemblers, except bad ones that have some random default for ambiguous cases).  The one I linked does mention AT&T syntax in Cody's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're asking about the *operand size suffix*.  There are two cases:

1. For many instructions, the operand size can be inferred from the operands themselves, typically because they are registers of a particular size.  This is like your example: `mov %rax, %rbx` must have a 64-bit operand size, because `%rax, %rbx` are 64-bit registers.  In this case, the suffix is optional, and the same machine code (`48 89 c3`) is generated whether you write `mov %rax, %rbx` or `movq %rax, %rbx`.  It's purely a matter of style whether you choose to include it or not (though certainly people have opinions about which way is better).

   If you provide a suffix that is inconsistent with the operands, e.g. `movl %rax, %rbx`, the assembler will give a warning or error.
2. In others, the operand size cannot be inferred.  The most common case is when one operand is an immediate and the other is a memory reference.  If you write `mov $1, (%rbx)` for ecm's example from comments, it is ambiguous: should the assembler emit an instruction to store a byte (machine code `c6 03 01`), or a word (two bytes, `66 c7 03 01 00`), or a long (four bytes, `c7 03 01 00 00 00`), or a quad (eight bytes, `48 c7 03 01 00 00 00`)?  So a suffix is required in this case: you must write `movb $1, (%rbx)` or `movw $1, (%rbx)` and so on.

   If you omit the suffix in such a case, recent assembler versions should at least warn you. Some will then abort with an error; others may guess at the operand size or use some built-in default, as Peter comments below. Some older assembler versions would actually revert to a default without warning.

So in principle, yes, omitting the suffix could lead to "wrong" code, in some cases and with some assemblers.  However, current versions of the widely used AT&T-syntax assemblers would at least warn you.

There is however one other way that this can sort of happen: suppose you want to add 5 to the 32-bit register `eax` (`addl $5, %eax`), but you make a typo and leave off the `e`.  If you are in the habit of using the suffixes, you would write `addl $5, %ax` and get an assembly error, alerting you to your mistake.  If your style is to omit them, you would write `add $5, %ax` and the code would build perfectly but would be "wrong".

Comment: Fun fact: for ambiguous instructions other than `mov`, GAS defaults to dword: e.g. `add $1, (%rax)` assembles to `83 00 01    add  DWORD PTR [rax],0x1`.  In the last year or so, GAS finally added a warning: *Warning: no instruction mnemonic suffix given and no register operands; using default for 'add'*.  I don't know how GAS ended up with this bad design, or why it didn't even warn until a very recent version.  (I have `as` 2.35.1), although I read something about Unix assemblers having a dword default.  clang's built-in assembler (correctly) rejects the ambiguous instruction.